# Why I get warning when trying to extend SplEnum?

Tags: php

```
class ArraySets extends SplEnum {
    const __default = self::EmptyArray;

    const Plugrush = 1;
    const JuicyAds = 2;
    const EmptyArray =0;
}
```

Zend Debugger told me that I cannot extends from interface SplEnum

What's wrong?

Is SplEnum a new thing? Do I need to install something for it to run?

Comment: SplEnum is part of SplTypes, and is a PECL extension not included with a standard PHP distribution - see http://prototype.php.net/manual/en/spl-types.installation.php for installation details